# Rails testing models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest

I'd like to test models working with each other. Something like this:

```
query = Query.new
user = users(:first)

assert_equal Query::STATUSES[:new], query.status

query.resend_to user.id

asser_equal Query::STATUSES[:resent], query.status
asser_equal 1, user.queries.size
```

But I even dont know, what is the right name for such kind of testing, scenario driven testing, behaviour driven testing?

Please, tell me how it's called and some examples.

Comment: "what is the right name for such kind of testing" - looks like regular unit testing.

Comment: but in regular unit testing we should avoid any dependencies, here we I'm changing states of query and user, and database

Comment: True, true. Call it integration testing then

Comment: But as I know integration testing is more like a testing from outside, check controllers, make GET request and etc